# how to display 2 fragments in a viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-xml

My application uses a ViewPager with 5 swipe tabs. I would like to inflate 2 fragments or 2 tab pages on my ViewPager when running the app on large devices and landscape orientation and 1 fragment or 1 tab page when running on smaller devices or portrait view. Also, it should still be able to swipe through all the tabs like I normally do when displaying single fragments on my ViewPager.

I initialized and inflate my ViewPager in my CourseFragment class which extends Fragment:

```
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(
            R.id.pagerYear);

    InfoTechPageAdapter infoTechPageAdapter = new InfoTechPageAdapter(
                getChildFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(infoTechPageAdapter);
```

My InfoTechPageAdapter which extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter:

```
package com.usjr.sss.adapter;

import com.usjr.sss.fragment.InfoTechFirstYearFragment;
import com.usjr.sss.fragment.InfoTechFourthYearFragment;
import com.usjr.sss.fragment.InfoTechSecondYearFragment;
import com.usjr.sss.fragment.InfoTechThirdYearFragment;
import com.usjr.sss.fragment.SubmitSubjectFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class InfoTechPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public InfoTechPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    Fragment mFragment;

    switch (pos) {

    case 0:
        mFragment = new InfoTechFirstYearFragment();
        mFragment.setArguments(null);
        return mFragment;
    case 1:
        mFragment = new InfoTechSecondYearFragment();
        mFragment.setArguments(null);
        return mFragment;
    case 2:
        mFragment = new InfoTechThirdYearFragment();
        mFragment.setArguments(null);
        return mFragment;
    case 3:
        mFragment = new InfoTechFourthYearFragment();
        mFragment.setArguments(null);
        return mFragment;
    case 4:
        mFragment = new SubmitSubjectFragment();
        mFragment.setArguments(null);
        return mFragment;

    default:
        return null;

    }

}// end getItem

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return 5;
}// end getCount

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int pos) {
    // Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
    switch (pos) {
    case 0:
        return "FIRST YEAR";
    case 1:
        return "SECOND YEAR";
    case 2:
        return "THIRD YEAR";
    case 3:
        return "FOURTH YEAR";
    case 4:
        return "SUBMIT";

    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

override in PageAdapter class.

```
@Override 
public float getPageWidth(int position) { 
return(0.5f); 
}
```